# NSThread - help with loading an image from a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nsthread

I'm trying to use threading to load an image from a url. I have no background code and I'm having trouble getting the NSThread thing to work. What I've got is a UIimageView called photo1 and I've got an image that loads in from the net. (say http://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png) but when navigating to the screen, the app pauses to load the image before hand. I was told to use NSThread to achieve this (watching the stanford U tutorial on it) but I'm having no luck at all getting it to work.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2009/11/remote-image-for-iphone/) which provides a RemoteImage class and uses an NSOperation to load images in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you don't use an `NSThread` to accomplish this, but rather use an asynchronous `NSURLConnection`.

Using the asynchronous URL connection won't block the UI, but will be much easier to use than maintaining all the boilerplate code required for an `NSThread`.

Look up the documentation for `NSURLConnection`, the parts you're interested in mainly are the bits on how to create an asynchronous connection and the delegate call backs.